# Run arangodb text file from command line

Tags: arangodb, aql

#### Description

In MySQL world, one can create an SQL file and execute it from the command line.

`mysql -h hostname -u user database < path/to/sqlfile.sql`

This is especially useful for test data.

I've checked the Arangodb documentation and the best I can see for putting in test data is this from the cookbook

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/examples-and-query-patterns/create-test-data/

Please is it possible to write an aql file and execute it in the command line like with MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to mysql SQL which contains [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) **and** [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) language elements, AQL by definition only contains DML statements. Therefore *"executing AQL"* is most probably not what suits your needs.

The arangosh [can be used to read files from the filesystem](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/javascript-api/fs/), which you then could use to send AQL queries or create collections and indices.

If you want a reproducible state, you could create a set of data that you like [maybe by creating a CSV to read using arangoimp](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangoimport/), create indices and so on, then [dump your database using arangodump](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangodump/) and for setting up your SUT use [arangorestore](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangorestore/).

There are tools by community members, [Migrant Verde](https://github.com/deusdat/migrantverde) and [ArangoMiGO](https://github.com/deusdat/arangomigo) that enable you to do schema evolution etc which may be of interest for that purpose too.